# How to adjust width of tabulary in landscape frame in latex?

Tags: multicolumn, landscape, tabulary

I use `tabulary` to fit my tables in big size to the text width for its simplicity and word wrap feature. But when I tried to fit my table to the whole page using landscape, I encountered a problem.

I used `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth` as suggested but the problem is that the width corresponds to the height for my rotated table in landscape.

The code of the table is:

```
\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength\tabcolsep{6pt}
\footnotesize
\def\arraystretch{1.2}
\centering 
\begin{table*}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{CLLCCCCCCCCC}%CLLCCCCCCCCC
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{8DB4E2} 
\multicolumn{12}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{8DB4E2}Optimize Edilmiş Yatırım ve İşletme Maliyeti}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{F2F2F2} 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{8DB4E2}Hat Uzunluğu}                   & Dudullu-Bostancı Metro Hattı                             & \cellcolor[HTML]{8DB4E2}İstasyon Sayısı         & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F2F2}10}                                             & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F2F2}}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F2F2}}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F2F2}}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F2F2}}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F2F2}}                                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F2F2}}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F2F2}}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F2F2}}                                               \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{F2F2F2} 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{8DB4E2}}                               & 11.90 km                                                 & \cellcolor[HTML]{8DB4E2}Yolcu Kapasitesi        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F2F2}35000}                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F2F2}}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F2F2}}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F2F2}}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F2F2}}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F2F2}}                                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F2F2}}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F2F2}}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F2F2}}                                               \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}                                                       &                                                          &                                                 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFC000}Yatırım Maliyeti}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DA9694}İşletme  Maliyeti}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{538DD5}Toplam}                                         \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFE36F}Trendeki Araç (vagon)   sayısı} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFE36F}Min. Pik sefer aralığpı (saniye) & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFE36F}Cer Sistemi (VDC)       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C5D9F1}Toplam İstasyon Yapım  Maliyeti (\euro)}        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C5D9F1}Toplam Hat Yapım  Maliyeti (\euro)}             & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C5D9F1}Toplam Araç alım Maliyeti (\euro)}              & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFC000}Trendeki Araç (vagon)   sayısı}                 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C4D79B}Min. Pik sefer aralığpı (saniye)}               & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C4D79B}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Cer \\   Sistemi  (VDC)\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C4D79B}Toplam İstasyon Yapım  Maliyeti (\euro)}        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DA9694}Toplam Hat Yapım  Maliyeti (\euro)}             & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{538DD5}Toplam Araç alım Maliyeti (\euro)}              \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FCF5EE} 
4                                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FCF5EE}99}           & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FCF5EE}750} & 93.678.063                                                                                 & 102.259.880                                                                                & 108.000.000                                                                                & 303.937.943                                                                                & 118.176.815                                                                                & 143.329.587                                                                                                 & 71.964.682                                                                                 & 333.471.084                                                                                & \cellcolor[HTML]{8DB4E2}637.409.027                                                        \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FCF5EE} 
5                                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FCF5EE}120}          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FCF5EE}750} & 114.586.331                                                                                & 100.159.139                                                                                & 115.000.000                                                                                & 329.745.470                                                                                & 130.307.910                                                                                & 155.837.417                                                                                                 & 76.597.791                                                                                 & 362.743.118                                                                                & \cellcolor[HTML]{8DB4E2}692.488.588                                                        \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FCF5EE} 
6                                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FCF5EE}150}          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FCF5EE}750} & 135.435.800                                                                                & 98.057.731                                                                                 & 108.000.000                                                                                & 341.493.531                                                                                & 142.439.004                                                                                & 156.638.660                                                                                                 & 74.390.900                                                                                 & 373.468.564                                                                                & \cellcolor[HTML]{8DB4E2}714.962.095                                                        \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FCF5EE} 
8                                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FCF5EE}210}          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FCF5EE}750} & 177.213.138                                                                                & 93.857.534                                                                                 & 104.000.000                                                                                & 375.070.672                                                                                & 166.701.193                                                                                & 161.201.774                                                                                                 & 74.897.119                                                                                 & 402.800.086                                                                                & \cellcolor[HTML]{8DB4E2}777.870.758                                                        \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{92D050} 
\multicolumn{12}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{92D050}Yatırım ve İşletme Maliyetleri arasındaki Farklar}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{92D050}4’lü dizi ile diğer diziler arasındaki farklar}                                                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C5D9F1}4’lü dizi ile diğer diziler arasındaki farklar} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C5D9F1}4’lü dizi ile diğer diziler arasındaki farklar} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C5D9F1}4’lü dizi ile diğer diziler arasındaki farklar} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFC000}4’lü dizi ile diğer diziler arasındaki farklar} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C4D79B}4’lü dizi ile diğer diziler arasındaki farklar} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C4D79B}4’lü dizi ile diğer diziler arasındaki farklar}                  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C4D79B}4’lü dizi ile diğer diziler arasındaki farklar} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DA9694}4’lü dizi ile diğer diziler arasındaki farklar} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{538DD5}4’lü dizi ile diğer diziler arasındaki farklar} \\
5                                                                          &                                                          &                                                 & 22,32\%                                                                                    & -2,05\%                                                                                    & 6,48\%                                                                                     & \textbf{8,49\%}                                                                            & 10,27\%                                                                                    & 8,73\%                                                                                                      & 6,44\%                                                                                     & 8,78\%                                                                                     & \textbf{8,64\%}                                                                            \\
6                                                                          &                                                          &                                                 & 44,58\%                                                                                    & -4,11\%                                                                                    & 0,00\%                                                                                     & \textbf{12,36\%}                                                                           & 20,53\%                                                                                    & 9,29\%                                                                                                      & 3,37\%                                                                                     & 11,99\%                                                                                    & \textbf{12,17\%}                                                                           \\
8                                                                          &                                                          &                                                 & 89,17\%                                                                                    & -8,22\%                                                                                    & -3,70\%                                                                                    & \textbf{23,40\%}                                                                           & 41,06\%                                                                                    & 12,47\%                                                                                                     & 4,07\%                                                                                     & 20,79\%                                                                                    & \textbf{22,04\%}                                                                           \\ \hline
\end{tabulary}
\end{table*}
\end{landscape}
```

The image of the page:

[image: The table is shown like this in the page]

Comment: the width of the table is the height of the page, that's the definition of landscape, what is the problem?

Comment: I can't adjust the column width and so the table doesn't fit to the page. When I use \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth} it just change the height of the table and the table still remain with long rows exceeding the pages through the top of the page.

Comment: all your large entries are in multicolumn `c` so forced to be single line with no wrapping, why have the multicolumn there rather than use the C from the table? but your example would be easier to debug if it were complete from \documentclass{article} to end{document}

Comment: It is a part of thesis and so a little bit complicated. Many document class.. I can share the package used if it helps. So do you think the problem is multicolumn? But I could handle it before (when no landscape used) using \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{LC..}. It simply set the table width to the linewidth and the problem solved. But here it changes the height of table and I can't adjust the actual table width :-/

Comment: please see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225/1090 on how to construct an example, we don't need to see your thesis text!

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- Please do make your example compilable, by providing a preamble that states all packages that are required to compile the table. I've had to make some educated guesses as to which packages are needed; I hope my guesses aren't too far off base.
- For the table at hand, use `\multicolumn{}{}{}` only when you need the material to span more than one column.
- Do (re)consider your color choices: the table looks downright gaudy, and it's not clear (to me at least) if any of the colors actually have a meaning, in terms of providing visual information about the structure of the table.
- Use shortcut macros, such as `\cc` and `\rc` (short for "cell color" and "row color"), to simplify the entering of the color-related information.
- I'm afraid I don't understand a word of Turkish. However, I'd say that your table is far to "chatty", and quite a few of the subheaders contain material that's (more or less) identical across cells. Do try to simplify the subheaders, e.g., by shortening the longer ones---ideally to just one or two words.
- If you're going to use colors as a dominant visual grouping device, I wouldn't use `\hline` as well (except maybe below the very last row of the table).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabulary,rotating,eurosym,amsmath,caption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}  % It is Turkish, right?
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page margins
\newcommand\cc[1]{\cellcolor[HTML]{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\newcommand\rc[1]{\rowcolor[HTML]{#1}}  % another handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}  % default: 6pt

\caption{My caption} \label{my-label}

\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{ *{3}{L} *{9}{C} }
%\hline
\rc{8DB4E2} 
\multicolumn{12}{c}{Optimize Edilmiş Yatırım ve İşletme Maliyeti}  
\\ 
%\hline
\rc{F2F2F2} 
\cc{8DB4E2} Hat Uzunluğu & Dudullu-Bostancı Metro Hattı & \cc{8DB4E2}İstasyon Sayısı
& \cc{F2F2F2}10
& \cc{F2F2F2} & \cc{F2F2F2} & \cc{F2F2F2} & \cc{F2F2F2} 
& \cc{F2F2F2} & \cc{F2F2F2} & \cc{F2F2F2} & \cc{F2F2F2} \\
\rc{F2F2F2} 
\cc{8DB4E2} & 11.90 km & \cc{8DB4E2}Yolcu Kapasitesi
& \cc{F2F2F2}35000 
& \cc{F2F2F2} & \cc{F2F2F2} & \cc{F2F2F2} & \cc{F2F2F2} 
& \cc{F2F2F2} & \cc{F2F2F2} & \cc{F2F2F2} & \cc{F2F2F2} 
\\
& & & 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\cc{FFC000}Yatırım Maliyeti} &  
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\cc{DA9694}İşletme  Maliyeti} & 
\cc{538DD5}Toplam  
\\
\cc{FFE36F}Trendeki Araç (vagon) sayısı & 
\cc{FFE36F}Min. Pik sefer aralığpı (saniye) & 
\cc{FFE36F}Cer Sistemi (VDC) & 
\cc{C5D9F1}Toplam İstasyon Yapım  Maliyeti (\euro) & 
\cc{C5D9F1}Toplam Hat Yapım  Maliyeti (\euro)&
\cc{C5D9F1}Toplam Araç alım Maliyeti (\euro)&
\cc{FFC000}Trendeki Araç (vagon) sayısı & 
\cc{C4D79B}Min. Pik sefer aralığpı (saniye)&
\cc{C4D79B}
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
     Cer \\   
     Sistemi  (VDC)
  \end{tabular} & 
\cc{C4D79B}Toplam İstasyon Yapım  Maliyeti (\euro)& 
\cc{DA9694}Toplam Hat Yapım  Maliyeti (\euro)&
\cc{538DD5}Toplam Araç alım Maliyeti (\euro) \\
\rc{FCF5EE} 
4 & \cc{FCF5EE}99 & \cc{FCF5EE}750
&  93.678.063 & 102.259.880 & 108.000.000 & 303.937.943  
& 118.176.815 & 143.329.587 &  71.964.682 & 333.471.084 & 
\cc{8DB4E2}637.409.027 
\\
\rc{FCF5EE}  
5 & \cc{FCF5EE}120 & \cc{FCF5EE}750 
& 114.586.331 & 100.159.139 & 115.000.000 & 329.745.470 
& 130.307.910 & 155.837.417 &  76.597.791 & 362.743.118  & 
\cc{8DB4E2}692.488.588 
\\
\rc{FCF5EE}  
6 & \cc{FCF5EE}150 & \cc{FCF5EE}750 
& 135.435.800 &  98.057.731 & 108.000.000 & 341.493.531
& 142.439.004 & 156.638.660 &  74.390.900 & 373.468.564 &
\cc{8DB4E2}714.962.095
\\
\rc{FCF5EE} 
8 & \cc{FCF5EE}210 & \cc{FCF5EE}750
& 177.213.138 &  93.857.534 & 104.000.000 & 375.070.672
& 166.701.193 & 161.201.774 &  74.897.119 & 402.800.086 & 
\cc{8DB4E2}777.870.758 
\\ 
%\hline
\rc{92D050} 
\multicolumn{12}{c}{\cc{92D050}Yatırım ve İşletme Maliyetleri arasındaki Farklar}
\\
%\hline
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\cc{92D050}
  \smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
              4’lü dizi ile diğer diziler \\
              arasındaki farklar\\
            \end{tabular}}}
& \cc{C5D9F1}4’lü dizi ile diğer diziler arasındaki farklar
& \cc{C5D9F1}4’lü dizi ile diğer diziler arasındaki farklar
& \cc{C5D9F1}4’lü dizi ile diğer diziler arasındaki farklar
& \cc{FFC000}4’lü dizi ile diğer diziler arasındaki farklar
& \cc{C4D79B}4’lü dizi ile diğer diziler arasındaki farklar
& \cc{C4D79B}4’lü dizi ile diğer diziler arasındaki farklar
& \cc{C4D79B}4’lü dizi ile diğer diziler arasındaki farklar
& \cc{DA9694}4’lü dizi ile diğer diziler arasındaki farklar
& \cc{538DD5}4’lü dizi ile diğer diziler arasındaki farklar
\\
5 & & & 
22,32\% & -2,05\% & 6,48\% & \textbf{8,49\%}& 
10,27\% &  8,73\% & 6,44\% & 8,78\% & \textbf{8,64\%}              
\\
6 & & & 
44,58\% & -4,11\% & 0,00\% & \textbf{12,36\%}& 
20,53\% &  9,29\% & 3,37\% & 11,99\% & \textbf{12,17\%}
\\
8 & & & 
89,17\% & -8,22\% & -3,70\% & \textbf{23,40\%}& 
41,06\% & 12,47\% &  4,07\% & 20,79\% & \textbf{22,04\%}           
\\ 
\hline
\end{tabulary}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the suggestions. In fact, this table is not my design. I'm just creating latex type of it. So I agree with you in terms of clarity of the table. I use online http://www.tablesgenerator.com/ tool to create latex tables. But for some special cases, it doesn't satisfy the need. 
>When different cells have different text align, it creates multicolumns like this: \multicolumn{1}{c}{...}

Comment: @beerobot - If tablesgenerator.com is really set up to encase all cells in `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` wrappers, I'd say it's not a suitable tool for use with the `tabulary` environment.